# I want my todo list items sorted even if I change the order myself

Tags: javascript, html, list, web

I have this code written and my customer wants this lists item's inner HTMLs to stay the same even if we change the places.

For example, if I go drag first element to the third place, the animation will occur but then, the list will stay the same as "Firs -> Second -> Third".

Any thoughts on how can I do it using JavaScript code?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drag & Drop Element</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.10.2/Sortable.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item first">
      <span class="text">First element</span>
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item second">
      <span class="text">Second element</span>
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item third">
      <span class="text">Third element</span>
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const dragArea = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
    new Sortable(dragArea, {
      animation: 350
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which list are you talking about?

Comment: you have a list of draggable div inside a container. You want the animation to occur (actually it's not animation but dragging and dropping) but you want the list to return to its original order once you dropped the item?

Comment: You can use a `data-id`=1, 2, 3 attribute to store the original order as a number